# Look up for highest value from another column if values are equal excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
***1   2   3***
   a   2   3
   b   3   4
   c   4   3
   d   5   2
```

so I know to get the highest value I do

```
=INDEX(column1, MATCH(MAX(column3), column3, 0))
```

... which would give me 'b'

now I want to get the second highest value based on the column 3 but because there are two cells with 3 (which is the second highest value) I want to use the one that has the lowest value in column 2 based on those two rows. Is this possible?

Comment: Use a 'helper' column that adds column C + (column B ÷ 10) and use your original formula on that column.

Comment: @pnuts - Going rogue with **xlR1C1** [XlReferenceStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821207.aspx) now?

Comment: sorting would mess up the calculations in those two columns, but the earlier suggestion is working fine. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'helper' column that adds column C + (column B ÷ 10) and use a modification of your original formula on that column.

[image: helper_max]

The standard formula in F5 is,

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5, MATCH(AGGREGATE(14, 6, D$2:D$5, ROW(1:1)), D$2:D$5, 0))
```

Fill down as necessary.